# Determine if the set is connected or not

Tags: real-analysis

Given the following definition:

*Definition*: Let $M$ be a metric space, $A, B \subset M $. Then

1. $A$ and $B$ are said to be *separated* if $A \cap \bar{B} = \emptyset = \bar{A} \cap B$.
2. A set $E \subset M$ is said to be *connected* if $E$ cannot be written as a union of two non-empty separated sets.

*Problem*: Is the following set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$E = \{ (x + y, x - y, xy) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$$
connected?

*My attempt:* Let $\mathbf{x} = (x + y, x - y, xy)$. Given this problem, I was trying to set $A = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$ and $B = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$. Then these two sets are separated, but $E$ cannot be written as a union of $A$ and $B$, therefore $E$ must be connected. Does this reasoning seem to be correct? I tried to play around with the values $(x + y, x - y, xy)$ given that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, but I am not sure what that can give us.

Comment: It is not correct because that only shows that $E$ is not the union of two particular separated sets, which doesn't imply that it is not the union of *some* particular separated sets.

Comment: The definition given is fine and easy to show a set is **not** connected: show one separated pair. To show connectedness one often uses theorems, like "intervals in complete linearly ordered topological spaces are connected" and "continuous images of connected spaces are connected" and many more. Have you drawn a picture of the set?

Comment: Ooh now I see. So, clearly the set of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ consists of all points as the boundary. Then, by a theorem: A subset $E$ of the real line is connected iff. it has the property: $x, y \in E$ and $x < z < y$, then $z \in E$. So I am assuming we can just check each entry of $\mathbf{x}$ defined above to show that it is connected? Unless a contradiction occurs of course

Comment: What properties of connected sets are you allowed to use? You could brute force this by expressing $E$ as a continuous curve in $\mathbb R^3$ or you could do it geometrically by rotating the  $xy$-plane by $45^{\circ}$, which will make it easier to see how the graph of $E$ looks.

Comment: Okay, so what I did was writing $t = x  + y$ then the second component of $\mathbf{x}$ is equal to $t - 2y$ and the third $yt - y^2$. We have that the expression $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is equivalent to $(t-y)^2 + y^2 = 1$ for any $y$. Setting $y = 0$, we find that $t = \pm 1$. So, we have two points $1$ and $-1$. And these two points are indeed disjoint and both lie on the unit circle, but there is no point in $E$ that lies between these two points, given that $y = 0$. Is this one way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The following property is basic and fundamental: If $X,Y$ are metric spaces, $X$ is connected, and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is a connected subset of $Y.$

Your problem can be viewed as $f:X\to Y,$ where $X$ is the unit circle $C\subset \mathbb R^2,$ $Y=\mathbb R^3,$ and $f(x,y) = (x+y,x-y,xy).$ If you can verify that $C$ is connected and $f$ is continuous on $C,$ then you're done.